# How to use python .replace with a codec value to remove special characters?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, encoding, codec

I have a dataframe I imported from excel that has a "-" in one of the string values in a column, but its not a regular dash and finally I found out what it was with looking at that cell and .encode('utf-8', errors = 'replace').
I can see the dash is really: \xe2\x80\x93
What I am trying to do now is change it to just a space. And I can't seem to get anything to work. I don't get errors but it doesn't update. I have tried:

```
df['column'].replace(b'\xe2\x80\x93', ' ')
df['column'].replace('\xe2\x80\x93', ' ')
df['column'].replace(b'\xe2\x80\x93', ' ', regex=True)
df['column'].replace('\xe2\x80\x93', ' ', regex=True)

dictionary = {'\xe2\x80\x93': ' '}
df['column'].replace(dictionary, regex=True)
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong and how to get this character to be replaced.

Comment: `df['column'].replace(b'\xe2\x80\x93'.decode('utf-8'), ' ')`? BTW, it's `–` {U+2013, 0xE2,0x80,0x93} _En Dash_

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this did not change it either...

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. At least: an example of your `df` (where `–` _En Dash_ is present), and a code snippet how do you get `df` …

Answer (score 0):

Try decoding it first:

```
df['column'].replace(b'\xe2\x80\x93'.decode('utf8'), ' ')
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this did not change it either...